# Dynamic array appending/exporting - Python

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, save, append

Pretty new to Python and have been struggling to create something that would save and append the new values of my output function into an array for export. Got this so far, but this ain't elegant

```
merit=5 #example input
MeritHist=[] #starting empty list
MeritHist.append(merit)

MeritArray=np.asarray(MeritHist) #turns into array
np.savetxt('test.out', MeritArray, delimiter=',')   #exports array
```

After the first run I hash the MeritHist=[] line so that it doesn't restart my list and then on subsequent runs new values are added like I want, but it just doesn't feel right...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
merit = 5
MeritHist = [merit]
MeritArray = np.asarray(MeritHist)
np.savetxt('test.out', MeritArray, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: It doesn't work right. It should be appending the array with a new value of 5 every time I run the code

Answer (score 0):

```
merit=5 #example input
MeritHist=[] #starting empty list
MeritHist.insert(-1,merit) ##insert to the beginning of the list 
print(MeritHist)


# or try this  
meritList= []
merit= input("Type a Number: ") 
meritList.append(merit)#aapend to the list 
print(meritList)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: It doesn't work right. It should be appending the array with a new value of 5 every time I run the code